# Check positive integer (not include zero ) in jquery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

The idea is to check only positive integer with no zero , however, the added custom rule do not work, how to fix it? Thank you.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#genForm").validate( {
      rules: {
         'fb' : {
              number: true
          },
     'order[]' : {
               required: true,
              number : true
          }, 
           parent: {
      required: function(element) {
        return $("#order[]").val() < 0 ;
      }}       

       }
   });

   $("#order[]").blur(function() {
  $("#parent").valid();
});
```

html:

```
foreach ($result as $set) // it determine how many text input box in total
{
<input type='text' id="order[]" name="order[]" >
}
```

further explanation:

```
 <input type='text' id="order[]" name="order[]" value="-1" > //not allowed case 1

 <input type='text' id="order[]" name="order[]" value="5" > //not allowed case 2
 <input type='text' id="order[]" name="order[]" value="5" > //not allowed case 2
 <input type='text' id="order[]" name="order[]" value="2" > //not allowed case 2
```

Comment: Have you defined `positiveinteger` as a custom rule anywhere?

Comment: sorry, how to define it? 
i have a regex 
"(^\d*\.?\d*[1-9]+\d*$)|(^[1-9]+\d*\.\d*$)" for this actually

Comment: You need to define it. Also, a regex is a poor choice when you could use `value > 0`.

Comment: You can see an example of custom validation method in their docs. Return true if it passes validation, false if not. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-callback

Comment: Thank you for  yours suggestion, i have add the custom rule , but it does not work still, are there any thing i am still missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure your syntax is correct here?

```
return order[] > 0;
```

Comment: besides the >0 , can i check the element in order[] are not the same? for example, the {2,2,1,5} is not allowed , thank you

Comment: Sorry but  I have tried  return $("#order[]") > 0 ; and <input type='text' id="order[]" name="order[]">

Comment: i don't completely get what you are trying to do here. are you trying to loop through all the elements in the order ARRAY, or is order a single element? Can you just explain all that you want to do, that might help.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. order[] is serveal text inputbox named order[] ,they should not <0  or have the same value of other inputbox. I have updated the question too, hope it can explain it. Please feel free to ask question if you have some part unclear.

Comment: Thanks your help, i have further explain it in real html case

Comment: sorry for the delay...from the updated question, u are making a grave mistake - ids must be unique. besides that you are using less than sign ( < ) in :
    return $("#order[]").val() < 0 ;
use >. see if that helps

Comment: Thanks actually  i use " min : 1" provided function and that 's all, problem solved. 
 however, the problem of check the order[] have same value still not fixed. That means if order[]={2,2,5,7} it should be invalid

Comment: so, 'order[]' is a single element, or is it an array of elements? since it contains multiple values?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10079/discussion-between-parth-thakkar-and-user782104)